# post 2 variable in html and php

Tags: php, post, get

in php i add a form in php file and i wanna to send variable in page join.php
the code is

```html
 $onlinelink='<form action="join.php" method="get">
                                                  
<button name="subject" type="submit" value="'.$coursename.'&'.'?userID='.$firstname.' "></button>
                  
</form>';
```

i wanna to correct link that post and get $coursename and $firstname when join.php file load
Thanks

Comment: If you want to use a form you should be using hidden elements with values instead of putting the value all on the submit button.

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is here.

Comment: It is fine to use navigation parameters such as size, page number, among others to send them by GET using "?", but for fields it is better to use POST and send them as part of the FORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form id="form1" type="POST" action="page1.php">
  <input name="cred1" value="ca">
  <input name="cred2" value="cb">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<a href="page2.php?coursename=math&username=smacaz&year=2020">go to page2</a>
<script>
  var form = document.querySelector("#form1");
  form.submit(function(e){
      // e.preventDefault();
      // Now you can do all validation and other things
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your original answer to add more information instead of posting a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
// page1.php (accessing the values sent through form post method)
if(isset($_POST["cred1"])){
  echo $_POST["cred1"];
}else{
  echo "No credentials found";
}
?>

<?php
// page2.php (accessing the values with $_REQUEST["..."])
if(isset($_REQUEST["coursename"])){
  echo $_REQUEST["coursename"];
}else{
  echo "No course name found";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send your data in a POST request to your join.php file.

Which would look like:

```html
<form action="join.php" method="POST"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="coursename" value="art">
    <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="John">
    <button name="subject" type="submit">Join Course</button>
</form>
```

Then in your join.php:

```php
<?php
$coursename = $_POST['coursename'];
$userID = $_POST['userid'];
```